# Finding out the prime factors of a number

Tags: java, primes, factors

This finds the prime factors of a number given in a variable. Is it efficient or in need of improvement?

```
public class PrimeFactorFinder {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        long n = 18;
        long md = 2;
        while(n!=java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)){

            if(n%md==0){
                System.out.print(" "+md);
                n /= md;
            } else {
                md++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The efficiency can be improved. As Simon already said, the condition

```
n != java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)
```

is equivalent to `n != 1`, and therefore not of much use.
Perhaps you meant something different: A composite number \$ n > 1 \$
must have a prime factor \$ p \$ for which  \$ p \le \sqrt n \$. Therefore,
as soon as `md > java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)` in your iteration, 
`n` is either equal to `1` or a prime number.

The code then is

```
    long md = 2;
    while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)) {
        if (n % md == 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + md);
            n /= md;
        } else {
            md++;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        System.out.print(" " + n);
    }
```

which reduces the number of iterations considerably:
For `n = 64_548_621` the loop runs until `md = 283` instead of
`md = 25343`.

Another small improvement is to repeatedly test a possible factor
in a while-loop, in order to save some square root computations
of the (updated) number `n`:

```
    long md = 2;
    while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)) {
        while (n % md == 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + md);
            n /= md;
        }
        md++;
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        System.out.print(" " + n);
    }
```

A simple measure to reduce the number of iterations to about 50% is to
test the factor 2 separately, and then only odd numbers starting
at 3:

```
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(" " + 2);
        n /= 2;
    }
    long md = 3;
    while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)) {
        while (n % md == 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + md);
            n /= md;
        }
        md += 2;
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        System.out.print(" " + n);
    }
```

As pointed out by @CodesInChaos [in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140457/java-code-to-find-out-prime-factors-of-a-number/140469?noredirect=1#comment263035_140469),
computing the square root of a long integer via floating point 
arithmetic can suffer from rounding issues.
This would be an issue for numbers greater than `2^52`.
From the analysis at [How can you easily calculate the square root of an unsigned long long in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499492/how-can-you-easily-calculate-the-square-root-of-an-unsigned-long-long-in-c/18501209#18501209)
it follows that the difference between 
`(long)java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)` and the correct 
value \$ \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor \$ is at most one.
Since only an upper bound is needed, replace the loop condition by

```
    while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n) + 1) {
```

If you want  *reusable* code then move the computation of
the prime factors in a separate function which returns the list
of primes. This also separates the computation from the I/O
and keeps the main function short:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PrimeFactorFinder {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        long n = 64_548_621;
        List<Long> factors = primeFactors(n);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(factors.toArray()));
    }

    static List<Long> primeFactors(long n) {
        List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<Long>();
        long md = 2;
        while (n % md == 0) {
            factors.add(md);
            n /= md;
        }
        md = 3;
        while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n) + 1) {
            while (n % md == 0) {
                factors.add(md);
                n /= md;
            }
            md += 2;
        }
        if (n > 1) {
            factors.add(n);
        }
        return factors;
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition `while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n))` still has the downside that it does the `sqrt` calculation (but in your case it might be worth it). But I like most parts of your answer, I thought about some of it but forgot it while I was writing your review.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: Thanks! – The rounding issues can be solved, but `if (md <= n/md)` is indeed slightly faster. I also tried to pre-calculate the square root and recompute it only if n changes, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a bit more efficient. One thing that could be optimized is to take bigger steps when increasing `md`. For example, when using the input value `64_548_621` the output is:

`3 3 283 25343`

This means that in about 25000 iterations the code `md++` was executed. If you instead would have a list of prime numbers and iterate through them, [there are 2735 primes in between](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+numbers+between+283+and+25343). However, as we're talking about computers and increasing numbers is really fast, I'm not sure if this would result in much bigger performance.

---

#### Other improvements

The condition for your while loop, `n != java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)` is an interesting one. And, speaking of performance, a slow one. Taking the square root of a number is not a trivial operation. As `n` always changes, this becomes a mathematical equation: \$n = \sqrt n\$.  The solution to this equation is \$1\$. Your loop will always stop at \$1\$ (unless you input the value zero in which case it will stop at zero, or input a negative number in which case you'll end up with an infinite loop always iterating on \$-1\$). It would be much much better to just write

```
while (n != 1)
```

---

My last comment is about naming, it's not clear what `n` and `md` is. Is it possibly short for `number` and `modulo`? Using the names `number` and `modulo` would be better.

Comment: `while (n != 1)` Won't that also loop infinitely if `n` is less than 1?

Comment: @mdfst13 Yes. Which should preferably be fixed with validating input. It could of course be changed to `while (n > 1)` or similar.

Comment: thanks, I used  n!=1  earlier but thought the program would take less iterations the Math.sqrt way, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>         while(n!=java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)){
> ```

As others have suggested, this could be either

> ```
>         while (n > 1) {
> ```

or

> ```
>         while (md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)) {
> ```

The former is simple to calculate but requires incrementing the potential factor to `n`.  The latter only requires increment to the square root of `n` but is computationally expensive.  Consider

```
        while (md * md <= n) {
```

That also iterates until `md` is greater than the square root of `n` but is cheaper to compute repeatedly.  You'd normally only take the square root if you were doing it outside the loop:

```
        long limit = (long)java.lang.Math.sqrt(n);
```

But in this case, `n` decreases and could be less than the square root of the original `n`.  So it makes sense to do the `md * md <= n` check.  Or

```
         while (md <= n / md) {
```

This is mathematically equivalent (so long as `md` is positive), and it might be computationally cheaper.  Some systems always calculate both `n / md` and `n % md` whenever calculating either one.  So doing both together is no more expensive than doing just one.  And you do `n % md` on every iteration of the loop already.

Comment: You are generally right about the performance difference between `md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)` and `md <= n / md`, but it is not as large as one might think. I could measure no noticeable difference for the "large prime" 1099511627791, and for the "very large prime" 1152921504606847009 is was approximately 13 vs. 14 seconds.

Comment: `md <= java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)` suffers from rounding issues. `md * md <= n` suffers from overflows if `n` is close to the maximum `long` can represent.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18501209/1187415 is an interesting approach to compute the integer square root correctly.

Comment: @MartinR Since we only need an upper bound, simply adding 1 to the square-root should suffice.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, but I found that answer interesting in itself. And I *think* `(long)java.lang.Math.sqrt(n)` should be exact up to 2^52 or so (the size of the mantissa).